# Python string literals - including single quote as well as double quotes in string

Tags: python

I want to join this series of strings:

```
my_str='"hello!"' + " it's" + ' there'
```

Want the result to be:

```
my_str
Out[65]: '"hello!" it's there'
```

But I get:

```
my_str
Out[65]: '"hello!" it\'s there'
```

I have tried a few iterations but none seem to work.

Comment: the result you want to get is impossible to achieve. By not escaping the `'` python would assume that this is the end of the string. You therefore need to escape it explicitly with the `\` for it to be parsed properly. You can actually see that quite nicely in stack overflow syntax highlighting

Comment: Try `print(my_str)` and tell us if there is really a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `print` command you will see as you want...

```
>>> my_str='"hello!"' + " it's" + ' there'
>>> my_str
'"hello!" it\'s there' #Count printed characters. You will count 22
>>> print my_str
"hello!" it's there
#Now count characters. 19
>>> len(my_str)
19
#see count of characters.
```

Using only "my_str" without any command/function shows only memory.
but if you want process with string u will get "'" without "\"...

Answer (score 3):

The result is correct. Single quotes have to be escaped in single quoted strings. The same for double quotes.

If you try `print` the result, you'll see that it's as you expected.

```
>>> print(my_str)
"hello!" it's there
```

Answer (score 0):

`print my_str` will print your string as

`'"hello!" it's there'`

You can also do that stuff in another way using `my_str.decode('ascii')`

```
new_str = my_str.decode('ascii')
print new_str
```

It will print the string as:

`"hello!" it's there`